# Question about using parquet for time-series data

Tags: apache-spark, time-series, parquet

I'm exploring ways to store a high volume of data from sensors (time series data), in a way that's scalable and cost-effective.

Currently, I'm writing a CSV file for each sensor, partitioned by date, so my filesystem hierarchy looks like this:

`client_id/sensor_id/year/month/day.csv`

My goal is to be able to perform SQL queries on this data, (typically fetching time ranges for a specific client/sensor, performing aggregations, etc) I've tried loading it to `Postgres` and `timescaledb`, but the volume is just too large and the queries are unreasonably slow.

I am now experimenting with using `Spark` and `Parquet` files to perform these queries, but I have some questions I haven't been able to answer from my research on this topic, namely:

I am converting this data to parquet files, so I now have something like this:

`client_id/sensor_id/year/month/day.parquet`

But my concern is that when `Spark` loads the top folder containing the many `Parquet` files, the metadata for the rowgroup information is not as optimized as if I used one single parquet file containing all the data, partitioned by `client/sensor/year/month/day`. Is this true? Or is it the same to have many parquet files or a single partitioned Parquet file? I know that internally the parquet file is stored in a folder hierarchy like the one I am using, but I'm not clear on how that affects the metadata for the file.

The reason I am not able to do this is that I am continuously receiving new data, and from my understanding, I cannot append to a parquet file due to the nature that the footer metadata works. Is this correct? Right now, I simply convert the previous day's data to parquet and create a new file for each sensor of each client.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the size of what you are writing every time?

Comment: It's hard to say since data intake is variable, but to give you some more context: Sensor data messages contain multiple readings [{sensor_id:sensor_value}, ..., {sensor_id:sensor_value}], but the number and variety of ids is unpredictable. I roll them out so that the table has a fixed schema (timestamp, id, value). So each message can be up to 30 rows, and I get thousands of messages per second. A little experiment I did with timescaledb ingesting data from kafka for a week yielded 2.8 billion rows.

Comment: Interesting stuff. Not quite what I have been involved in (yet).

Comment: What solution did you finally chose? I'm facing a very similar problem here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Structured Streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html) with kafka(as you are already using it) for real time processing of your data and store data in parquet format. And, yes you can append data to parquet files. Use SaveMode.Append for that such as
`df.write.mode('append').parquet(path)`

You can even partition your data on hourly basis.
client/sensor/year/month/day/hour which will further provide you performance improvement while querying. 
You can create hour partition based on system time or timestamp column based on type of query you want to run on your data.

You can use [watermaking](https://towardsdatascience.com/watermarking-in-spark-structured-streaming-9e164f373e9) for handling late records if you choose to partition based on timestamp column.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello wypul. I have used structured streaming with spark before. I don't think that the data transformation step is my bottleneck for now. I know that you can append to parquet, my question was whether there was a performance hit since the row groups need the data to compute the metadata beforehand. Queries are not done on an hourly granularity so I guess going further down on the partitioning won't bring any benefits. I'll try your suggestion anyway to benchmark the transformation step vs what I have now. Thank you

Comment: Hello @mlashcorp do you have the time to share  your final solution? :)

Answer (score 0):

I could share my experience and technology stack that being used at AppsFlyer.
We have a lot of data, about 70 billion events per day.

Our time-series data for near-real-time analytics are stored in Druid and Clickhouse. Clickhouse is used to hold real-time data for the last two days; Druid (0.9) wasn't able to manage it. Druid holds the rest of our data, which populated daily via Hadoop.

Druid is a right candidate in case you don't need a row data but pre-aggregated one, on a daily or hourly basis. 
I would suggest you let a chance to the Clickhouse, it lacks documentation and examples but works robust and fast.

Also, you might take a look at Apache Hudi.